# fetching data from 2 tables based on that select third table data using mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a 3 table and want to fetch table like given below

```
table bonus               table dealer                  accountdetail
-----------               -------------                ----------------

id   type commission     id   by whom  commission     id    account number
--- ----- ----------    ---- ------- -----------    ----  -----------
1    book  100          1      john     50            1    5423456789
2    pen   15           3      rana     20            2    4563778599
                                                      3    5679087765
```

Code is:

```
(select b.id,
        b.commission, 
        ac.account  
 from bonus b, 
      accountdetail ac
 where  ac.id = b.id 
order by ac.id)

union all
(select d.id,
        d.commission,
        ac.account  
 from dealer d, 
 accountdetail ac 
 where  ac.id = d.id 
 order by ac.id)
```

out put is:

```
    id   commission   account number
    ---  ----------   -----------
    1      100         5423456789
    1      50          5423456789
    2      15          4563778599
    3      20          5679087765
```

but i want to out put like that

```
id   commission   account number
---  ----------   -----------
1      150         5423456789
2      15          4563778599
3      20          5679087765
```

please suggest me how to union the records and show data once with calculation

thanx in advance

Comment: How are the tables related?

Comment: Where does `150` come from? Are you adding the commissions from the `dealer` and `bonus` tables?

Comment: This appears to be a simple 3-way join, where you return `bonus.commision + dealer.commission`.

Comment: yes i want to do sum of bonus.commision + dealer.commission  @ barmar

Comment: Show what you tried. We don't write it for you, we help you fix your code when it doesn't work.

Comment: ok thanx , i solved it by using sum() for each query and selecting both union by alias table using another sum() function